# OpenLayers calculating wrong bbox for tiles

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver

I have a map file from MapServer (having to use MapServer instead of GeoServer since the datasource is an ESRI fgdb) defined with the following:

```
MAP
    NAME dalguy72__gushelpsme1
    STATUS ON
    SIZE 1000 800   
    CONFIG PROJ_LIB "C:\ms4w\proj\nad"
    CONFIG GDAL_DATA "C:\ms4w\gdaldata"
    CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "C:\ms4w\ms_error.txt"
    DEBUG 5
    FONTSET "C:\ms4w\apps\etc\fonts.txt"
    EXTENT  1987903.97499337 5109905.52499218 2025400.77513921 5152089.97516415
    PROJECTION 
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END 
    WEB
      METADATA
        "wms_title" "dalguy72__gushelpsme1 for dalguy72"
        "wms_onlineresource" "https://maps.mountain-viewgroup.com:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/dalguy72__gushelpsme1/dalguy72__gushelpsme1.map"
        "wms_enable_request" "*"
        "wms_srs" "epsg:4326"
        "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
        "wms_format" "image/png"  
        "wfs_title" "Demo1 Project"
        "wfs_onlineresource" "https://maps.mountain-viewgroup.com:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/dalguy72__gushelpsme1/dalguy72__gushelpsme1.map"
        "wfs_srs" "epsg:4326"
        "wfs_abstract" "Demo Test"
        "wfs_enable_request" "*"
      END
    END
    LAYER
        NAME "goodproject1__aa1__a1__nw__watershed_evaluation"
        TYPE POLYGON
        STATUS ON
        PROJECTION 
            "init=epsg:4326"
        END 
        METADATA 
            "wms_title" "goodproject1__aa1__a1__nw__watershed_evaluation"
            "wfs_title" "goodproject1__aa1__a1__nw__watershed_evaluation"
            "wfs_srs"    "epsg:4326"
            "wfs_crs"  "crs:84"
            "gml_include_items" "all"
            "gml_featureid"  "objectid"
            "wfs_enable_request" "*"
        END
        CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
        CONNECTION "C:\ms4w\apps\dalguy72__gushelpsme1\data\export.gdb\exportme.gdb"
        DATA "goodproject1__aa1__a1__Merged"                
        CLASS
            NAME 'VERY LOW'
            TEMPLATE "C:\ms4w\apps\dalguy72__gushelpsme1\goodproject1__aa1__a1.html"
            EXPRESSION([nw__watershed_evaluation] < -.6)
            STYLE
                COLOR 255 0 0 
                OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
            END         

        END
        CLASS
            NAME 'LOW'
            TEMPLATE "C:\ms4w\apps\dalguy72__gushelpsme1\goodproject1__aa1__a1.html"

            EXPRESSION([nw__watershed_evaluation] > -.6 AND [nw__watershed_evaluation] < -.2)
            STYLE
                COLOR 240 128 128
                OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
            END         

        END
        CLASS
            NAME 'MODERATE'
            TEMPLATE "C:\ms4w\apps\dalguy72__gushelpsme1\goodproject1__aa1__a1.html"

            EXPRESSION([nw__watershed_evaluation] > -.2 AND [nw__watershed_evaluation] < .2)
            STYLE
                COLOR 229 204 255
                OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
            END         

        END
        CLASS
            NAME 'HIGH'
            TEMPLATE "C:\ms4w\apps\dalguy72__gushelpsme1\goodproject1__aa1__a1.html"

            EXPRESSION([nw__watershed_evaluation] > .2 AND [nw__watershed_evaluation] < .6) 
            STYLE
                COLOR 142 229 238
                OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
            END         

        END
        CLASS
            NAME 'VERY HIGH'
            TEMPLATE "C:\ms4w\apps\dalguy72__gushelpsme1\goodproject1__aa1__a1.html"

            EXPRESSION([nw__watershed_evaluation] > .6)
            STYLE
                COLOR 0 0 139
                OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
            END
        END
    END
END
```

And I modified the WMS capabilities parsing example from the OpenLayers site, with the new HTML script portion:

```
<script>
      var layers = [       
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          extent: [1987903.97499337,5109905.52499218,2025400.77513921,5152089.97516415],
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'https://maps.mountain-viewgroup.com:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/dalguy72__gushelpsme1/dalguy72__gushelpsme1.map',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'goodproject1__aa1__a1__nw__watershed_evaluation', 'TILED': true},projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            serverType: 'mapserver'
          })
        })
      ];
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [2006652.37506629, 5130997.750078165],
          zoom: 7
        })
      });
    </script>
```

However, when the BBOX is generated for each tile, is like:

```
BBOX=42.1875%2C18.28125%2C43.59375%2C19.6875
```

If I change it to be CSR:83, then I get an error that CSR parameter is incorrect.  Is there a way of specifying the bounding box instead of dynamically having openlayers do it, or is there another layer type I should use in this case?

Comment: Fixed some of the formatting - please review. Also, `CSR:83` - is that a typo?

Comment: There seem to be a few issues here, which might be cause you problems.  First off, according to the map file, the service only supports EPSG::4326, so any request from a client in a projection other than EPSG::4326 will be rejected by the server, and won't show on your map.

Comment: There is no parameter `"wfs_crs"` for specifying coordinate reference systems supported by WFS use `wfs_srs`, for a WMS use `wms_srs` and if your service has wms and wfs and you want the same coordinate reference systems to be used by both you can instead use `ows_srs`.  You can have more than one CRS specified in a space separated list.  The order of the list only matters for WFS, in which case the first listed should be the default.

Comment: `CSR:` is a misspelling, it must be `CRS:`